# Custom class(inheritrance TransformerMixin),sklearn2pmml generates PMML file report encoding error

Tags: python-3.x

I've customized a class to replace strings with null values for use in the DataFrameMapper.
when I used sklearn2pmml to generate a PMML file,I reported an encoding error.

This is my example transformer:

```
class DataEncode(TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self   
    def transform(self,X):
        X = X.replace("\\N",np.nan)
        X = X.replace("-",np.nan)
        X = X.astype(float)
        return pd.concat([X],axis=1)
```

DataFrameMapper:

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    (['Sepal.Length'],[DataEncode(),ContinuousDomain(),Imputer(),StandardScaler()]),
    (['Sepal.Width'],[DataEncode(),ContinuousDomain(),Imputer(),StandardScaler()]),
    (['Petal.Length'],[DataEncode(),ContinuousDomain(),Imputer(),StandardScaler()]),
    (['Petal.Width'],[DataEncode(),ContinuousDomain(),Imputer(),StandardScaler()]),
],input_df = True)
```

Training model:

```
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline
gbdt_pipline = PMMLPipeline([
    ('mapper',mapper),
    ('classifier',clf)
])
```

PMML file:

```
sklearn2pmml(gbdt_pipline,"D:/mlfile/test/test_iris.pmml",with_repr=True,debug=True)
```

error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-8e29dc6f358c> in <module>()
----> 1 sklearn2pmml(gbdt_pipline,"D:/mlfile/test/test_iris.pmml",with_repr=True,debug=True)

D:\anaconda-hh\lib\site-packages\sklearn2pmml\__init__.py in sklearn2pmml(pipeline, pmml, user_classpath, with_repr, debug)
    231                                 print("Standard output is empty")
    232                         if(len(error) > 0):
--> 233                                 print("Standard error:\n{0}".format(error.decode("UTF-8")))
    234                         else:
    235                                 print("Standard error is empty")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried many ways but I couldn't.I wonder if custom classes are not supported.
I tried to change the encoding and convert it to PMML through pkl but nothing worked
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SkLearn2PMML package **does** support custom transformers and models. However, to make things work across different platforms, you need to implement both Python-side and Java-side conversion logic. At the moment the Java-side is missing.

Please see the [SkLearn2PMML-Plugin](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml-plugin) project for step-by-step instructions.

If the goal is to simply detect and replace invalid numeric values, then you don't need to create a custom transformer class, because the default `sklearn2pmml.preprocessing.ContinuousDomain` can already do it:

```
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
  (['Sepal.Length'], [ContinuousDomain(invalid_value_replacement = float("NaN")), Imputer(), StandardScaler()])
])
```

Comment: At first, I misunderstood. Do I need to convert python code into the java-plugin? Maven then compiles the project and gets the jar. Set the jar in sklearn2pmml to generate PMML files